# Joining two R dataframes on multiple columns with one column having slightly different values

Tags: r, left-join

I have two dataframes in R that I'm trying to join together, but one of the columns has values that are off by one or two (specifically the `yardline_100` column in each). Below is the code that I'm using to join the two:

```
fin_df <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2,
            by = c("posteam" = "posteam",
                   "qtr" = "qtr", 
                   "down" = "down",
                   "yardline_100" = "yardline_100"))
```

Is there any way to make it so that they join even if that one column is off by one or two? You'll notice that the last two values rows have different numbers in that column. Below are samples of the dataframes:

```
df1 <- structure(list(play_id = c(4596, 4629, 4658, 4682, 4723, 4766, 
4790, 4828, 4849, 4878, 4899, 4938), posteam = c("MIN", "MIN", 
"MIN", "MIN", "MIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", 
"CIN"), qtr = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), yardline_100 = c(63, 
58, 55, 50, 38, 61, 55, 52, 52, 20, 15, 15), down = c(2, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("nflverse_data", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.table", "data.frame"), nflverse_timestamp = structure(1659046255.35538, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), nflverse_type = "play by play", nflfastR_version = structure(list(
    c(4L, 3L, 0L, 9020L)), class = c("package_version", "numeric_version"
)), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000021967f81ef0>)

df2 <- structure(list(posteam = c("MIN", "MIN", "MIN", "MIN", "MIN", 
"CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN", "CIN"), qtr = c(5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), yardline_100 = c(63, 58, 55, 
50, 38, 61, 55, 53, 52, 20, 16, 16), down = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3), play_id_SR = c("a9f97fb0-1407-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", 
"d49d54d0-1407-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", "e8f74ad0-1407-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", 
"0208ae60-1408-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", "257fd030-1408-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", 
"fe058030-1408-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", "0da68200-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", 
"26a5bd20-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", "70eacce0-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", 
"99e5fb10-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", "a7646b00-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022", 
"de2683d0-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022")), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: How do you know which values are different in `yardline_100`? In your case, the last two values in `yardline_100` in df2 are different from those in df1. Is there any general pattern in your data?

Comment: @jazzurro I had to manually find the ones that were causing issues. There doesn't seem to be a clear pattern.

Comment: If that is the case, I think what Maurits Evers suggested would be one potential approach. If you have `play_id` in both data frames, you could check if there is any gap in `yardline_100` . Alternatively, you could do the same if you can create unique ID for each row.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `fuzzyjoin`.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
df1 %>% 
    fuzzy_left_join(
        df2,
        by = c("posteam", "qtr", "down", "yardline_100"),
        match_fun = list(`==`, `==`, `==`, function(x, y) abs(x - y) <= 2)) %>%
    select(-matches("(posteam|qtr|down).y")) %>%
    rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "(?<=(posteam|qtr|down)).x"))
## A tibble: 12 x 7
#   play_id posteam   qtr yardline_100.x  down yardline_100.y play_id_SR                          
#     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>                               
# 1    4596 MIN         5             63     2             63 a9f97fb0-1407-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
# 2    4629 MIN         5             58     1             58 d49d54d0-1407-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
# 3    4658 MIN         5             55     2             55 e8f74ad0-1407-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
# 4    4682 MIN         5             50     3             50 0208ae60-1408-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
# 5    4723 MIN         5             38     1             38 257fd030-1408-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
# 6    4766 CIN         5             61     1             61 fe058030-1408-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
# 7    4790 CIN         5             55     2             55 0da68200-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
# 8    4828 CIN         5             52     3             53 26a5bd20-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
# 9    4849 CIN         5             52     4             52 70eacce0-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
#10    4878 CIN         5             20     1             20 99e5fb10-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
#11    4899 CIN         5             15     2             16 a7646b00-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
#12    4938 CIN         5             15     3             16 de2683d0-1409-11ec-ae9a-d77d9ecb2022
```

Note the matching function `function(x, y) abs(x - y) <= 2` for column `"yardline_100"`.

The last two lines (`select(...)` and `rename_with(...)`) are necessary to remove the duplicate columns: `fuzzyjoin` seems to create duplicate (i.e. ".x" and ".y"-suffixed) columns even on exact matches; the last two commands remove these duplicate exact match columns.